# Infopath to Sharepoint: Create multiple list items based on a date range?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

Incredible new to Sharepoint and may be in over my head!

I've been mandated to create a system that records projected capacity use versus actual capacity usage for my department. We are already recording the actual capacity and have data for each calendar day.

For the projected capacity I need to have users be able to input how much capacity they think they will need for the various phases of a project. Once again I'm leaning on InfoPath.

Each phase has a project id, start date, end date, and the capacity required. This is currently done through infopath. Phases may begin on any date. The capacity value will remain constant for the whole phase.

Here's where I'm stuck: This data in the infopath form then needs to be converted so that for each day in the range provided a list item is created (e.g. If the Initial phase goes from Jan 1st to Jan 14th I need to create 14 list items: 1 for each day in the range referencing the project ID and the requested capacity).

Can anyone point me towards a practical solution?

Many thanks in advance!